# How do I use regular expressions in Jinja2?

Tags: regex, jinja2

I'm new to Jinja2 and so far I've been able to do most of what I want. However, I need to use regular expressions and can't seem to find anything anywhere in [the documentation](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/) or on Google.

I'd like to create a macro that mimics the behavior of this in Javascript:

```
function myFunc(str) {
    return str.replace(/someregexhere/, '').replace(' ', '_');
}
```

which will remove characters in a string and then replace spaces with underscores. How can I do this with Jinja2?

Comment: Regex filters had been added in 2017. See https://docs.saltstack.com/en/develop/topics/jinja/index.html#regex-replace

Comment: That link is a 404 now.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

There is an already existing filter called [`replace`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#replace) that you can use if you don't actually need a regular expression.  Otherwise, you can register a [custom filter](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/api/#custom-filters):

```
{# Replace method #}
{{my_str|replace("some text", "")|replace(" ", "_")}}
```

```
# Custom filter method
def regex_replace(s, find, replace):
    """A non-optimal implementation of a regex filter"""
    return re.sub(find, replace, s)

jinja_environment.filters['regex_replace'] = regex_replace
```

Comment: yeah this is the way i ended up going, unfortunately. it's dumb you can't use regex in jinja2

Comment: hey, man! You say it is a non-optimal implementation, could you ellaborate on what would look like the optimal one?

Comment: @elias - since `find` is compiled each time it is used by `re.sub` if this was used as a filter in a large loop it could *potentially* be a bottleneck.  If that were the case you could either add a keyword arg to the filter (`cache`) and compile and store `find` args when `cache` was set to `True` - or you could just compile and cache all `find` arguments and choose an ejection strategy that best suites your application.

Comment: @SeanVieira (Sorry for the late comment) It's worth noting that Python's re module caches compiled regexes automatically since at least as far back as 1.5.2 (and the cache size was raised to 100 in 2.0). Depending on how many regexes are in play in the app, the benefit of a cache might already be covered.