# Regex matching in jinja2 filters (for use in saltstack)

Tags: regex, jinja2, salt-stack

It seems Jinja2 (as supported in Saltstack) doesn't support regex matching, unless I'm missing something?  A number of frameworks that leverage Jinja2, such as [Ansible have custom support](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_filters.html) for regex filters.  [Elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12791216/how-do-i-use-regular-expressions-in-jinja2) people are directed to write custom filters.

Some questions for those in the know, would probably help understand this state of affairs:

1. What would be the best way to leverage regex matching in Saltstack?  (my use-case here is reasonably simple: testing if a string ends with a substring but the question is more general).
2. In the absence of a standard solution in Jinja2, would it be a good idea for this to be offered as a standard extension in Saltstack (akin to the Ansible solution)?
3. What's the rationale for not having standard regex support in Jinja2?  In a world where [even Windows Powershell](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/6bfc6f90-5dfa-4b4c-b6e8-f401906e0a5c) supports regex matching, there must be a reason I'm missing since [this perceived regression from Jinja2 compared to the previous version has been complained about since 2010](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pocoo-libs/3yZl8vHJ9fI); however there isn't even an issue for this in [Jinja's github](https://github.com/pallets/jinja/issues) that I could find?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an oldish post, but I came across it and to help other people that do the same..

SaltStack does now have regex_search and regex_match as of 2017.7.0:

https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/jinja/index.html#regex-search

Answer (score 6):

Even if its old this is still the top post when googling for salt match regex. In 2018.3.3 it is possible to write following code:

```
{% if "abc" is match("*b*") %}
...
{% endif %}
```

The relevant documentation link: https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/jinja/index.html#match

Answer (score 2):

You can match both State and Pillar files like this,

for example, Top.sls

```
base:
 '*':
   - servers.{{ grains.id }}
   {% if grains.id | regex_match('nyc(.*)', ignorecase=True) %}
   - data.region.nyc
   {% endif %}
   - ignore_missing: True
```

any node matching nyc* will get these pillar values. This also works inside State files (tested on 2018.3.4)