# Remove URL prefix in Django

Tags: html, django

In Django model URLs stored in URL field, so the values are look like "https://example.com/id"
In HTML rending with pure Django rending code should be without *https://* prefix like this

```
<script src="https://coolservice.js" url="{{ example.com/id }}" </script>
```

Can't find any embedded Django filters or elegant solution how to remove prefix on the fly without extra coding in DB

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/12825283/11404396 (You want to replace 'https://' with '')

Comment: not really. When I added replace to the script above - I got an error "Namespace 'https' is not bound " since js can't handle so much special characters )))
e.g. it didn`t work <script src="https://coolservice.js" url="{{ example.com/id |replace("https://", "" }}" </script> 
the error marked on first //

Comment: I`ve just realized I don't use jinja here, but pure Django build-in filters. Sorry for misguiding, I already modified the initial question

Comment: So, I assume we can close this question, since the answer is NO, but I found two alternatives: Create a custom Django filter or create a new char field in model instead of URL field (so you can store in normal char field values already without http prefix)